# Motion sensors not working on phone (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sensors

This is my first time using motion sensors. I followed the code here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-build-an-application-to-test-motion-sensors-in-android/

I also watched Youtube videos on these sensors examples and they show the sensors working on the emulator, but when I try to do it myself using my phone (connected with USB cable), it doesn't work. The screen doesn't change color when I move the phone.

I looked in the Developer Options setting on the phone but there's nothing about enabling motion sensors so it must have been enabled already, but it's still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's because your phone doesn't have this sensor. Some sensors like compass or accelerometer are not available on all devices

Comment: I just checked and my phone (Samsung J7 prime) does have accelerometer

Comment: J7 prime does have an accelerometer but it doesn't have a gyroscope. And to use a motion sensor you need both.